# Find phone number along with its city code in excel

Tags: excel, phone-number

I Have some address from which I need to extract phone number along with its city code.
Here is the column

```
A
T.C-29-877 (2), CPRA 0124-414210 mob:8578451021
T-Win Park,Westside 211-1421522 fgas-14201
Whitefield, rose bunglow 01221-2102125
Q-Part,bilmore,521-145212 abc@gmail.com
```

Here I want to extract

```
0124-414210
211-1421522
01221-2102125
521-145212
```

I tried with seperating with the delim `-` but since there can be multiple `-` in a text so it didn't worked for me.

Is there any which can be used to extract these values?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Domnick

Comment: Is use of VBA acceptable? If so, edit your question to add `excel-vba` and `vba` tags.

Comment: Will you ever have something like `814-2938 zz 2929-222` where you only want one of those two? In other words, can we assume that anything formatted like `##-###` or `####-###` is the number you want?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes the Numbers of the format `###-#####` can be considered as the wanted text.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij sorry but I'm not being allowed to use vba code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is in cell A1 try following array formula which needs to be committed by pressing **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**. And then copy down.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",199)))," ",REPT(" ",199)),SEARCH(MAX(IFERROR(-(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$256),COLUMN($A$1:$IV$1)))+0,0)),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",199)))," ",REPT(" ",199)),1)-99,199))`

If applied correctly Excel will wrap formula with braces.